# Can we limit the domain we visit from ios in-app browser?

Tags: ios, browser

I am developing an ios app, and I wish to use the in-app browser. But I wish to limit the domain visited with in-app browser. (Ex: limited to the .com website only.) Is there a way to implement this restriction?

Answer (score 2):

> Sent before a web view begins loading a frame.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

> Parameters
>
> webView The web view that is about to load a new frame. request The
>   content location. navigationType The type of user action that started
>   the load request.
>
> Return Value
>
> YES if the web view should begin**
>   **loading content; otherwise, NO .**

You should always read the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to know if you can do something with a web view, start by looking at the documentation - [UIWebView class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

From there, you can see that it has [a `delegate` property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWebView/delegate) that is sent messages when content is loading.  So next, you look at [the documentation for the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006951).

From there, you can see that the delegate is sent [a `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` message](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView%3ashouldStartLoadWithRequest%3anavigationType%3a) before the web view loads content.  Looking at the documentation for that method tells you that you need simply return `NO` from that method to cancel loading content.

So provide a delegate for the web view that implements that method which returns `NO` when you see a URL you don't like.

In future, please check the documentation before asking on Stack Overflow.